# Apache2: having trouble setting new projects

Tags: linux, linux-mint, symbolic-link, apache-http-server

I just installed LAMP on Linux Mint 15 and ran into troubles when setting up my projects. First I tried putting a symlink into the /var/www directory that points to the project folder in my home directory. That didn't work and now I copied the whole project into the var/www/ and got the same error.

The index pages work fine but everything outside the public folders seems unreachable, other controllers for example. I just get 404 messages: 'The requested URL was not found on this server.'

I've searched for help and read about adding some lines to the sites-available file to enable following symlinks but that didn't change a thing.

my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride Indexes
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Anybody got a clue as to why it won't work properly? I haven't changed anything in any other file. It seems there's just one piece missing …

Comment: What's your index.html look like?  Are the links in the files relative?  What's the URL that is accessed, vs. the file path on the system?  What does the Apache log show?  Lots of possibilities to check . . .

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the project directories?